# FileNotFoundException uploading an image to Oracle database

Tags: exception, servlets, filenotfoundexception, servletexception, ojdbc

I have made a servlet program to insert image into an Oracle database. The program is as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class InsertImage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url=request.getParameter("image");
        File image=new File(url);
        FileInputStream fis;
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String str = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(str,"system","root");
            PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into insertimage(image) values(?)");
            fis = new FileInputStream(image);
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
            int size=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if(size>0)
            {
                pw.println("<html>Image Uploaded Successfully.</html>");
            }
            else
            {
                pw.println("<html>Image could not be uploaded.</html>");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML page, from where the input is coming is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="InsertImage" name="form1">
            INSERT IMAGE
            <input type="file" name="image"></input>
            <input type="submit" name="upload"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this code from the HTML page, whatever picture input I give, it always throws `FileNotFoundException`. I can't understand why I am getting this. The `stacktrace` is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Counter-Strike-Servers.jpg (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at InsertImage.doGet(InsertImage.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to print the URL in the servlet and got only **shocked.jpg** and not the full `filepath`. Maybe the full `filepath` is not coming and that is the cause of not finding the file error. So how can I send the full `filepath`?

Comment: This is not how file/image upload works.

Comment: Are you storing it in Blob type in oracle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While uploading a file from JSP/HTML, you must have the form method set to `POST` with `encType` set to `multipart/form-data`. ([HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3))

```
<form action="InsertImage" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
```

Implement the `doPost` method to get the same file. You may want to take a look at [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to upload files and Stack Overflow post *[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)* for further details.

I tried one way to upload the file without using the Apache Common FileUpload and it's working.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="InsertImage" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            INSERT IMAGE
            <input type="file" name="image"></input>
            <input type="submit" name="upload"></input>
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>

    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet doPost:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url=request.getParameter("image");
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    pw.println("Reading file");
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         pw.println(line);
    }
    pw.flush();
}
```

Now you have to parse the file contents as per your needs. Refer blog post *[Upload and store files](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/11/multipartfilter.html)*. However, I would strongly suggest using ***Apache Commons FileUpload*** for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a local error in the sense that it really can't find the file specified by `url`. I would suggest debugging by printing out the `url` String and creating a dummy class to feed the `doGet` method a handmade request/response to make sure whether the problem is in the program itself or in some unexpected passing/formating of the request (you might want to comment out some parts of the method for this, e.g. the connection and statement part).

**EDIT:** Example of the dummy class (or method, in this case):

```
private void testDoGet() {
    // I would suggest commenting out all the Connection and PreparedStatement
    // parts of the doGet method so you don't have to establish the connection.
    // - this is just to test if you can get to the image on your machine.
    HttpServletRequest request;
    //insert into request the image parameter with the string to the requested image
    HttpServletResponse response //TODO initialize with some class implementing it
    doGet(request, response);
    // if you want to, set a breakpoint somewhere here to check 
    // what's in the classes now        
}
```

Comment: I could not get **creating a dummy class to feed the doGet method a handmade request/response to make sure whether the problem is in the program itself or in some unexpected passing/formating of the request** part!!

Comment: It is only printing **shocked.jpg** i.e the picture name itself, not the class path. That gives me sense the full filepath is not coming and that's why it can't find the file. So what can i do to get the exact path?

Comment: It is probably relative path, not absolute - it starts in the folder the program is running from (if you're running it from an IDE it is usually the project folder). As a first step try moving the requested file there.

Comment: @SubirAdhikari: you will only get file name not path. Consider a situation where your server and client are at different location and you are uploading a file.